# Adding new user contact fields also in user-new.php in wordpress

Tags: php

I have already found a code the let me add new user contact fields, the problem is that I can just edit these fields, but when I'm creating a new user I dont see these fields immediatly, my desire is having these fields from the start in the page user.new.php, and of course the content should "stick"

```
//adding contact fields to user profile 

function extra_contact_info($contactmethods) {
    
    $contactmethods['fax'] = 'Fax';
    $contactmethods['address'] = 'Indirizzo';
    $contactmethods['postalcode'] = 'Codice Postale';
    $contactmethods['town'] = 'Comune';
    $contactmethods['country'] = 'Paese';
    $contactmethods['taxcode'] = 'Codice fiscale';

    return $contactmethods;
}
add_filter('user_contactmethods', 'extra_contact_info');
```